# PostgreSQL JSON_TABLE - Syntax error near COLUMNS

Tags: postgresql

Has anyone been able to get the new PostgreSQL feature for JSON_TABLE() to work? I have used it with another database and was excited to learn that PostgreSQL was to be implementing it with version 15.

We have installed version 15.2, and based on the simple example I found at
https://www.depesz.com/2022/04/06/waiting-for-postgresql-15-json_table/

Where I tried the example:

```
select * from json_table(
    '[{"a":10,"b":20},{"a":30,"b":40}]'::jsonb,
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS (
        column_a int4 path '$.a',
        column_b int4 path '$.b'
    )
);
```

However, I get a response of "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "COLUMNS""

Is there a typo in the example? I've only found a couple of examples. All give the same error.

Comment: No, it did not make it into 15 as you can see [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html). But it seems it will be part of 16

Comment: The article is discussing a proposed patch, not necessarily the released postgres 15

Comment: @Bergi: it was actually part of the first beta. But after that, some serious problems were found and the team decided to remove it before the final release.

Comment: Yeah I remember, https://www.depesz.com/2022/09/02/sql-json-is-postponed/